# Homogeneous distribution variance and correlation

Tags: probability

The random variable $X$ has a homogeneous distribution in the interval $(0,1)$ and $Y = X ^ k, k> 0.$ Calculate the variance and the correlation coefficient between the variables $X$ and $Y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By some integration, we can find all these. Since this is a unit interval, the expected values are the "unweighted" integrals:
$$\overline X=E[X]=\int_0^1x\,dx=\frac12\left[x^2\right]_0^1=\frac12$$
$$\overline Y=E[Y]=\int_0^1x^k\,dx=\frac1{k+1}\left[x^{k+1}\right]_0^1=\frac1{k+1}$$
and the variances are
$$\sigma_X^2=\mathrm{Var}(X)=E\left[(X-\overline X)^2\right]
=\int_0^1\left(x-\tfrac12\right)^2\,dx=\tfrac13\left[\left(x-\tfrac12\right)^3\right]_0^1=\tfrac1{12}$$
$$\sigma_Y^2=\mathrm{Var}(Y)=E\left[(Y-\overline Y)^2\right]
=\int_0^1\left(x^k-\tfrac1{k+1}\right)^2\,dx,$$
the latter of which can be found by
first multiplying out and then integrating,
or using $E[Y^2]-E[Y]^2$ then integrating,
and lastly simplifying to get
$$\sigma_Y^2=\frac{k^2}{(k+1)^2(2k+1)}.$$
Similarly, the covariance is
$$\sigma_{XY}=\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)
=E\left[(X-\overline X)(Y-\overline Y)\right]
=E[XY]-E[X]E[Y]$$
$$=\int_0^1x^{k+1}\,dx-\tfrac1{2(k+1)}
=\tfrac1{k+2}-\tfrac1{2k+2}
=\frac{k}{2(k+1)(k+2)}$$
so that the (Pearson) correlation coefficient is
$$
\mathrm{Corr}(X,Y)
=\frac{\sigma_{XY}}{\sigma_X\sigma_Y}
=\frac{\sqrt{3(2k+1)}}{k+2}.
$$